# Flushing pipe without closing in C

Tags: c, pipe, eof, flush

I have found a lot of threads in here asking about how it is possible to flush a pipe after writing to it without closing it.
In every thread I could see different suggestions but i could not find a definite solution.

Here is a quick summary:

1. The easiest way to avoid read blocking on the pipe would be to write the exact number of bytes that is reading.
2. It could be also done by using ptmx instead of a pipe but people said it could be to much.

Note: It's not possible to use fsync with pipes

Are there any other more efficient solutions?

Edit:

The flush would be convenient when the sender wants to write n characters but the client reads m characters (where m>n). The client will block waiting for another m-n characters. If the sender wants to communicate again with the client leaves him without the option of closing the pipe and just sending the exact number of bytes could be a good source of bugs.

The receiver operates like this and it cannot be modified:

```
while((n=read(0, buf, 100)>0){
     process(buf)
```

so the sender wants to get processed: "file1" and "file2" for which will have to:

```
write(pipe[1], "file1\0*95", 100);
write(pipe[1], "file2\0*95", 100);
```

what I am looking is for a way to do something like that (without being necessary to use the \n as the delimeter):

```
write(pipe[1], "file1\nfile2", 11); //it would have worked if it was ptmx
```

(Using read and write)

Comment: This sounds very much like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Generally speaking, there is no need to flush a pipe, so what's the real issue?

Comment: And what do you mean by "pts"?

Comment: @John: I was referring to pseudoterminal master/slave. I have updated the original post.

Comment: If your receiver indeed operates the way you describe then it is broken.  If it cannot be modified then your best bet is to choose a different project.  Your approach of padding the writes to the expected read length is the best available way of feeding data to the broken receiver (modulo the possible problem of short writes), but it is not guaranteed to work reliably.  In particular, if the writer gets far enough ahead of the reader to fill the pipe's buffer to capacity, then it is *likely* that the writer and reader will fall out of sync.  Not that they are otherwise sure to stay in sync.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  can you elaborate more? What intrigues me is the "generally speaking" part of your comment. Is there any unusual situation in which we need to flush a pipe?

Comment: @rkioji the "generally speaking" was me hedging against the possibility of an implementation or scenario that I had not thought of.  I still have not thought of or become aware of any such.  However, you may be interested in my actual answer, below.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks! Does the same apply for named pipes? I ask this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149805/do-i-need-to-flush-named-pipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flushing in the sense of `fflush()` is irrelevant to pipes, because they are not represented as C streams.  There is therefore no userland buffer to flush.  Similarly, `fsync()` is also irrelevant to pipes, because there is no back-end storage for the data.  Data successfully written to a pipe exist in the kernel and only in the kernel until they are successfully read, so there is no work for `fsync()` to do.  Overall, flushing / syncing is applicable only where there is intermediate storage involved, which is not the case with pipes.

With the clarification, your question seems to be about establishing message boundaries for communication via a pipe.  You are correct that closing the write end of the pipe will signal a boundary -- not just of one message, but of the whole stream of communication -- but of course that's final.  You are also correct that there are no inherent message boundaries.  Nevertheless, you seem to be working from at least somewhat of a misconception here:

> The easiest way to avoid read blocking on the pipe would be to write
>   the exact number of bytes that is reading.
>
> [...]
>
> The flush would be convenient when the sender wants to write n
>   characters but the client reads m characters (where m>n). The client
>   will block waiting for another m-n characters.

Whether the reader will block is entirely dependent on how the reader is implemented.  In particular, the `read(2)` system call in no way guarantees to transfer the requested number of bytes before returning.  It can and will perform a short read under some circumstances.  Although the details are unspecified, you can ordinarily rely on a short read when at least one character can be transferred without blocking, but not the whole number requested.  Similar applies to `write(2)`.  Thus, the easiest way to avoid `read()` blocking is to ensure that you write at least *one* byte to the pipe for that `read()` call to transfer.

In fact, people usually come at this issue from the opposite direction: needing to be certain to receive a specific number of bytes, and therefore having to deal with the potential for short reads as a complication (to be dealt with by performing the `read()` in a loop).  You'll need to consider that, too, but you have the benefit that your client is unlikely to block under the circumstances you describe; it just isn't the problem you think it is.

There is an inherent message-boundary problem in any kind of stream communication, however, and you'll need to deal with it.  There are several approaches; among the most commonly used are

- ***Fixed-length messages.*** The receiver can then read until it successfully transfers the required number of bytes; any blocking involved is appropriate and needful.  With this approach, the scenario you postulate simply does not arise, but the writer might need to pad its messages.
- ***Delimited messages.*** The receiver then reads until it finds that it has received a message delimiter (a newline or a null byte, for example).  In this case, the receiver will need to be prepared for the possibility of message boundaries not being aligned with the byte sequences transferred by `read()` calls.  Marking the end of a message by closing the channel can be considered a special case of this alternative.
- ***Embedded message-length metadata.***  This can take many forms, but one of the simplest is to structure messages as a fixed-length integer message length field, followed by that number of bytes of message data.  The reader then knows at every point how many bytes it needs to read, so it will not block needlessly.

These can be used individually or in combination to implement an application-layer protocol for communicating between your processes.  Naturally, the parties to the communication must agree on the protocol details for communication to be successful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added some more notes to my original question, but what i am looking is the answer to this: `It can and will perform a short read under some circumstances` Which are those circumstances?

Comment: @AntonisParagas, I have already addressed that in my answer to the greatest extent possible: "Although **the details are unspecified**, you can ordinarily rely on a short read when at least one character can be transferred without blocking, but not the whole number requested."  That is, `read()` ordinarily will not block when it can transfer at least one byte.